# Docker Apache2 + Tomcat 8.5, Virtual Host -- HTTPS not working

Tags: docker, ssl, apache2, virtualhost, tomcat8

I've set up two Docker containers: An apache2 and a tomcat8, the latter named "**tomcatCon**". I want to use apache2 as proxy for the web site which is hosted within tomcat. The two containers are running without errors. I've started them with:

```
sudo docker run -d --name tomcatCon -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 tomcat
sudo docker run -dit --name apache2Con --link tomcatCon:tomcatCon -p 80:80 -p 443:443 apache2
```

Below, my **/etc/hosts**:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost    
127.0.0.1    www.my_site.com wws.my_site.com
```

Below, the excerpt of interest from my **/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.my_site.com
CustomLog logs/http_access.log common
ErrorLog logs/http_error.log

RewriteEngine On
LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

ProxyPass             /site     http://tomcatCon:8080/site
ProxyPassReverse      /site     http://tomcatCon:8080/site

Header edit Set-Cookie ^JSESSIONID=([^;]+);(.*) JSESSIONID=$1;domain=.my_site.com;path=/site;
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.my_site.com
ServerAlias wws.my_site.com
CustomLog logs/https_access.log common
ErrorLog logs/https_error.log

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/apache2/ssl/server.key

RewriteEngine On
LogLevel warn rewrite:trace3

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^(GET|POST|HEAD)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

ProxyPass             /site     https://tomcatCon:8443/site
ProxyPassReverse      /site     https://tomcatCon:8443/site
</VirtualHost>
```

And the excerpt from my **server.xml** tomcat configuration file:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
         maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
         clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS">
```

If I open **http://www.my_site.com/site/home.html** in the browser, it works fine. I also find the expected traces in the **logs/http_access.log** file of my apache2. However, when I try to open for instance **https://wws.my_site.com/site/login.html**, the browser shows an error message *"Secure connection failed"*. And there are no traces whatsoever in **logs/https_access.log** and **logs/https_error.log**.

Being under Ubuntu, I've also tried:

```
sudo curl https://wws.my_site.com/site/login.html
```

and what I get is:

```
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to wws.my_site.com:443
```

Comment: The two container not are on the same (docker) network. Use [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) or use the [--network](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/) parameter

Comment: I could use docker-compose, but this is not the issue I think. The containers are both in the default network (because no explicit network has been passed as an argument) and as I stated, the HTTP virtual host works well. It's the HTTPS that doesn't work...

Comment: With SSL you must configure, on `wws.my_site.com`, a valid certificate trusted by a valid CA. You can use _openssl_ for this operation.

Comment: @Max you're probably right. We finally opted for using AJP connectors between apache and tomcat.